# Confusion about posix pipe with respect to kernel fd table

Tags: c, pipe, posix

I'm trying to understand how pipes work. From my understanding, a kernel has a file descriptor table where each element points to things like files and pipes etc. So a process can write to or read from a pipe when the correct file descriptor is specified.

In the example I've found below, a file descriptor is made of an array and a pipe is created using that. The program then forks so that there's a child copy. This is where I get confused, the child closes fd[0] so that is cannot recieve information from the parent? It writes some data to fd[1]. The parent then closes fd[1] and reads from fd[0]. This seems wrong to me, the parent is reading from the wrong place?

```
int main(void)
{
        int     fd[2], nbytes;
        pid_t   childpid;
        char    string[] = "Hello, world!\n";
        char    readbuffer[80];

        pipe(fd);

        if((childpid = fork()) == -1)
        {
                perror("fork");
                exit(1);
        }

        if(childpid == 0)
        {
                /* Child process closes up input side of pipe */
                close(fd[0]);

                /* Send "string" through the output side of pipe */
                write(fd[1], string, (strlen(string)+1));
                exit(0);
        }
        else
        {
                /* Parent process closes up output side of pipe */
                close(fd[1]);

                /* Read in a string from the pipe */
                nbytes = read(fd[0], readbuffer, sizeof(readbuffer));
                printf("Received string: %s", readbuffer);
        }

        return(0);
}
```

Am I wrong and actually both fd elements reference the same point in the kernel's table? Intuitively I thought it would be creating two pipes. If they are the same position in the table what is the structure of a pipe where it can interpret these different read and writes?

Apologies if this is being too vague, I'm having real trouble wrapping my head around it. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: A pipe is a kernel-managed object characterized (in part) by *two* file descriptors -- one for writing to it, and a different one for reading from it.  The `pipe()` function creates such an object and records the two FDs in the specified array; the one for reading is stored at index 0 and the one for writing at index 1, which you can remember by analogy with the stdin and stdout file descriptors (0 and 1, respectively).  It is conventional, and sometimes necessary, for a process using a pipe to close the end it does not intend to use.

Answer (score 0):

When you `fork` a new process, the child has an exact copy of the open file descriptors. How this is implemented can be considered "magic" or whatever as we don't really need to know how, only that it does work. They share them and if both tried reading from `stdin` (for example) you'd get unpredictable results because they're both reading from the same place. It's only when all processes close a file descriptor does it truly get closed.

So in the case of your `pipe`, the child and parent can close the end of the pipe they're not going to use without worrying about the end they do care about from closing unexpectedly. If one of them opens another file, it may re-use the same file descriptor id of the recently closed one.